# Get last result ruby into if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am kind of new in ruby. So i was experimenting and vanted to print last array record a litle bit difrent ! Here's the code:

```
    <h1>Wellcome to the Frige</h1>

<p> These are current inventory items: </p><br />
<% @frige.each do |items| %>
    <%
        if items == items.last
            %>
                And <%= items %> <br />
            <%
        else
            %>
                <%= items %> <br />
            <%
        end

     %>
<% end %>
<br />
<br />
<hr />
<%= link_to "Go tu the Shop", pages_frige_path %>
```

Here's the Ressult :

Wellcome to the Frige

These are current inventory items:

Tomatoes 
Potatoes 
Meat 
Chrips

Doties uz Veikalu

Tnx for help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is that you don't want `if items == items.last`, you want `if items == @frige.last`.

Comment: I am compleate idiot, tnx mate :) I kinda understand the problem and the solution :) Good day to you sir.